# How to stop Pymakr from restarting the board

Tags: vscode-extensions, esp32, micropython

When, in Visual Code with the Pymakr extension, one sets the development mode to automatically synchronize any change in the local files with the device, Pymakr reboots the device every time a file is saved.

How can I prevent this behaviour?
Important: Not looking for a workaround. I do not want the reboot to happen at all.

I have googled for it
I have checked the Pymakr extension settings and the settings.json

PD: I can't undestand why this is not an option in the extension (or, maybe, I did not find it?)

Comment: I took a look in github:
https://github.com/pycom/pymakr-vsc/blob/HEAD/GET_STARTED.md
If you scroll down to 'Developer mode', It has a line "onUpdate" you can add or modify in `pymakr.json`. Try to see if you can find that and remove the line or set it to an empty string.

Comment: @Roman I have tried that option and also:
  "reboot_after_upload": false,
  "ctrl_c_on_connect": true,
  "safe_boot_on_upload": false,
None of them working